How to trigger one job in Jenkins by multiple repositories in Bitbucket?
I've got a problem with Jenkins. I'm using Bitbucket Server Integration plugin and I want to configure one job to start reading Jenkinsfile from repository when I push some changes to one of my repos. When I'm start configuring my job I can only choose one repo in my job configuration when in code repository section I select bitbucket server. I'm using bitbucket server version. Can Someone know maybe how to solve this problem? Thank for help.

Have you thought of creating webhooks in Bitbucket and trigger the job in Jenkins.
You can create Generic web-hook trigger job in Jenkins and use the job name in Bitbucket Repository web-hook.
Whenever you push some code into the bitbucket, the job will trigger.

Nice idea, Can i by this plugin start a job only when i push for example when i wanna create finished a pull request to branch develop ?

Yes, The wehbook event can be on push / on PR creation / on PR merge

It works really nice thanks :D !

You are looking for a Multibranch pipeline plugin, specifically its Organization Folder feature. It works in combination with another plugin - Bitbucket Branch Source.
There is a good guide here.
